# ra-data-graphql-simple can not find resource

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin

I am trying to use **react-admin** as my admin panel and using **ra-data-graphql-simple** to fetch from graphql API.
the problem is that it can not find my resource and I got this error:

`Unknown resource Category. Make sure it has been declared on your server side schema. Known resources are`

Here is my code.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import buildGraphQLProvider from 'ra-data-graphql-simple';
import { Admin, Resource, Delete, ListGuesser  } from 'react-admin';

import apolloClient from './apolloSetup';

import { CategoryList } from './categories';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { dataProvider: null };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        buildGraphQLProvider({ clientOptions: { uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3434/graphql' }})
            .then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));
    }

    render() {
        const { dataProvider } = this.state;

        if (!dataProvider) {
            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        return (
            <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
                <Resource name="Category" list={ListGuesser} />
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and the apolloSetup.js

```
import { HttpLink, createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3434/graphql',
  mode: 'no-cors',
});

export default new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: httpLink,
});
```

Here is my Graphql schema. (The category parent id is always 1.)

```
# source: http://127.0.0.1:3434/graphql


type Category {
  body: String
  disabled: Boolean
  id: ID
  image: Upload
  parentId: ID
  title: String
  user: User
}

"""Autogenerated input type of ConfirmOtp"""
input ConfirmOtpInput {
  mobile: String!
  otp: String!

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
}

"""Autogenerated return type of ConfirmOtp"""
type ConfirmOtpPayload {
  accessToken: String

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
  errors: [String!]!
}

"""Autogenerated input type of CreateCategory"""
input CreateCategoryInput {
  title: String!
  body: String
  parentId: ID
  image: Upload

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
}

"""Autogenerated return type of CreateCategory"""
type CreateCategoryPayload {
  category: Category

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
  errors: [String!]
}

"""Autogenerated input type of CreatePost"""
input CreatePostInput {
  title: String!
  body: String
  categoryId: ID!
  image: Upload
  video: Upload

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
}

"""Autogenerated return type of CreatePost"""
type CreatePostPayload {
  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
  errors: [String!]!
  post: Post!
}

"""Autogenerated input type of GenerateOtp"""
input GenerateOtpInput {
  mobile: String!

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
}

"""Autogenerated return type of GenerateOtp"""
type GenerateOtpPayload {
  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
  result: String
}

type Mutation {
  confirmOtp(input: ConfirmOtpInput!): ConfirmOtpPayload
  createCategory(input: CreateCategoryInput!): CreateCategoryPayload
  createPost(input: CreatePostInput!): CreatePostPayload
  generateOtp(input: GenerateOtpInput!): GenerateOtpPayload
}

type Post {
  body: String
  category: Category
  disabled: Boolean
  id: ID
  image: Upload
  title: String
  user: User
  video: Upload
}

type Query {
  """List of all categories or categories of a directory"""
  categories(parentId: ID): [Category!]

  """Returns the current user"""
  currentUser: User!

  """Find a post by ID"""
  post(id: ID!): Post

  """List of all posts"""
  posts(categoryId: ID!): [Post!]
}

scalar Upload

type User {
  mobile: String!
}
```

Should I create a custom data provider? If yes, how should I create it for this schema?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the source code, you will notice that the Resource is knownResource if it has a minimum of type:

```
Query {
   Post (id: ID!): Post
   allPosts (page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: PostFilter): [Post]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Under the covers ra-data-graphql-simple uses the 'pluralize' library, and is extremely sensitive to case, etc, when evaluating if a resource is available.  It will ignore a resource if it doesn't have a correctly cased version, and at least the GET_ONE, GET_LIST Query elements.  So, for the original post 'Category' would need at least "allCategories" and "Category" to show up as a Query'able item.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still stuck on this, I'd suggest reducing down your schema to just the Category type and relevant mutations. See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql-simple#expected-graphql-schema for the expected GraphQL schema format for ra-data-graphql-simple. Try swapping in your resource to this format to begin with. ra-data-graphql-simple is quite picky and if it doesn't like your schema it'll just ignore the resource (hence your error message with no resources).